# Event for inspector updates

Tags: unity

Is there an event I can subscribe to from a static class that will trigger every time the inspector is changed, similar to OnValidate()?

Or do I have to have a monobehaviour running to detect inspector changes?

### EDIT

To clarify

Project is a sandbox with many variables exposed both through in-game gui and in inspector. I have a somewhat convoluted system to allow the same variable to be editable from any location and in real time update all other instances where it is exposed, whether editor or game gui.

That's why I want onValidate() - so that designer can set presets from editor without having to use in game gui.

However I'm using a generic class to hold the variables so it can be passed around as a reference:

```
[Serializable]
public class HEventProperty<T>
{
    public string name;

    [SerializeField] private T value;
    public HEventProperty()
    {
        value = default;
        Init();
    }
    public HEventProperty(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        Init();
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get => value;
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }

    public event Action<T> OnChanged;

    private void Init()
    {
        UpdateValue();
        InspectorDetector.InspectorChanged += UpdateValue;
    }
    private void UpdateValue()// todo should be just one way to change the value see above
    {
        OnChanged?.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

For this to work the UpdateValue method must be called every time the variables are edited. In-game, this is handled in a wrapper class that syncs this EventProperty with a given UI element and updates based on events from the UI element:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace UIScripts
{
    public class ToggleWrapper
    {
        private readonly HEventProperty<bool> _boolParam;
        private readonly Toggle _toggle;

        public ToggleWrapper(Toggle toggle, HEventProperty<bool> boolParam)
        {
            _toggle = toggle;
            _toggle.isOn = boolParam.Value;
            _toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { Update(); });
            _boolParam = boolParam;
            boolParam.OnUserChanged += UpdateToggle;
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            _boolParam.Value = _toggle.isOn;
        }

        private void UpdateToggle(bool v)
        {
            _toggle.isOn = _boolParam.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want is a similar event that I can subscribe to when the inspector is changed, but from a non-monobehaviour class.

The solution I ended up with yesterday is a helper class with an event that is referenced by all HEventProperties

```
public static class InspectorDetector
{
    public static event Action InspectorChanged;
    public static void Update()
    {
        InspectorChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Which in turn is called from any class containing inspector variables when OnValidate() is called.

Works, perhaps there is a cleaner way?

Any critique very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: OnValidate() is an Editor-only function. You shouldn't use it at runtime. Static classes(non-monobehaviour  classes?) are not associated with inspector so do you mean member variables?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Can you tell us what you are *actually* trying to accomplish? Perhaps we can tell you a better approach to solving this problem.